# Getting a dataset format merging two datasets

Tags: python, pandas

I have two datasets:

```
Customer1       Customer2       Relationship   Age_of_Relationship
Alfa              Wolk               1                  12
Cyrius           Century             0                   1
Cyrius           Mercedes            0                  10
Apple            Microsoft           1                   4
Apple            Google              0                   3
Microsoft        Google              0                  12
```

and

```
All_Customers      Net      Recovered
Alfa             12412          1
Wolk             12435          0
Cyrius           14532          1
Century          12521          0
Mercedes         12353          0
Apple            15412          0
Microsoft        6412           1
Google           12146          1
```

I am trying to include information from df2 into df1 in order to have the following expected output:

```
Customer1       Customer2       Relationship   Age_of_Relationship     Net    Recovered
Alfa              Wolk               1                  12            12412     1 
Wolk              Alfa               1                  12            12435     0
Cyrius           Century             0                   1            14532     1
Cyrius           Mercedes            0                  10            14532     0
Century          Cyrius              0                   1            12521     0
Mercedes         Cyrius              0                  10            12353     0
Apple            Microsoft           1                   4            15412     0
Apple            Google              0                   3            15412     0
Microsoft        Google              0                  12            6412      1
Microsoft        Apple               1                   4            6412      1
Google           Apple               0                   3           12146      1
Google           Microsoft           0                  12           12146      1
```

I think that I need to consider a merge but I guess that only a merge would not work in this case, then return the expected output.

Comment: Looks like you might need to copy the first df, swap the customer columns, concat the two df's together, then do a merge.

Comment: Hi Chris, it is not clear how to swap the customer columns. Could you please tell me more on how to swap them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest method is to copy the original dataframe and rename all of the columns the way you want, which in this case involved swapping the first two names.  Then you can concatenate them and merge with your second dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Customer1': ['Alfa', 'Cyrius', 'Cyrius', 'Apple', 'Apple', 'Microsoft'],
 'Customer2': ['Wolk', 'Century', 'Mercedes', 'Microsoft', 'Google', 'Google'],
 'Relationship': [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
 'Age_of_Relationship': [12, 1, 10, 4, 3, 12]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'All_Customers': ['Alfa',
  'Wolk',
  'Cyrius',
  'Century',
  'Mercedes',
  'Apple',
  'Microsoft',
  'Google'],
 'Net': [12412, 12435, 14532, 12521, 12353, 15412, 6412, 12146],
 'Recovered': [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]})

# Copy original dataframe
df_copy = df.copy()

# Swap customer1 and customer 2 names
df_copy.columns = ['Customer2','Customer1','Relationship','Age_of_Relationship']

# Concat df and the copy w/the swapped columns, and merge w/df2
pd.concat([df,df_copy]).merge(df2, left_on='Customer1',right_on='All_Customers').drop(columns=['All_Customers'])
```

Output

```
   Customer1  Customer2  Relationship  Age_of_Relationship    Net  Recovered
0        Alfa       Wolk             1                   12  12412          1
1      Cyrius    Century             0                    1  14532          1
2      Cyrius   Mercedes             0                   10  14532          1
3       Apple  Microsoft             1                    4  15412          0
4       Apple     Google             0                    3  15412          0
5   Microsoft     Google             0                   12   6412          1
6   Microsoft      Apple             1                    4   6412          1
7        Wolk       Alfa             1                   12  12435          0
8     Century     Cyrius             0                    1  12521          0
9    Mercedes     Cyrius             0                   10  12353          0
10     Google      Apple             0                    3  12146          1
11     Google  Microsoft             0                   12  12146          1
```